# Three.ar.js bad aspect ratio creating stretched image?

Tags: javascript, android, three.js, webvr, arcore

Don't really know how to formulate the question but i got some pictures that might make things clear. In the ones i conveniently called 'bad aspect' you can see the video being a bid skewed/warped/stretched. 
The good and the bad one are based off the same demo project: https://github.com/google-ar/three.ar.js/blob/master/examples/spawn-at-surface.html 
I made printscreens on my smartphone with both apps where i hold my phone in portrait mode and then turn it diagonally.

[image: good aspect1]

[image: good aspect2]

[image: bad aspect1]

[image: bad aspect2]

And i think the clue can be found here:
[image]

It makes drawingbufferheight into 4096 and i think it should be 5661, like the viewportheight. Tried changing it manually but i can't seem to make that work. Any ideas or clues?

(Using three.js, three.ar.js and the webVR API)

edit: some code:

```
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true});   
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.autoClear = false;
    this.canvas = this.renderer.domElement; 


    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene(); 

    // Creating the ARView, which is the object that handles
    // the rendering of the camera stream behind the three.js
    // scene
    this.arView = new THREE.ARView(this.vrDisplay, this.renderer);
```

Comment: Probably got a -1 because i didnt add some code, i'll add it.
it's basically the same as the demo project though but the difference is that it's initiated as a class from a remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not relevant anymore, i use another version now as they released a fix. What exactly happened remains a mystery

Answer (score 1):

Although I am using Unity, this was an observed issue with ARCore Preview 1. Are you using Preview 1 or 2? If 1, I suggest you update to preview 2 to see if it fixes the issue. If the issue is not fixed on Preview 2 you should report it in ARCore github issues.

Comment: i'm using WebArOnARCore, as far as i know i cant choose which preview i can use. Got both installed on the phone so i could try checking if it just picks the first one installed on the phone OR if there's somewhere in the code a pointer to which APK is used?

Comment: Thanks for the comment by the way, may i ask how you know this was an observed issue? I checked most of the issues but i never found anything that relates to this

Comment: What version of the sdk are you using? The code changed from p1 to p2 so you should know which you're using. I know if the issue because I reported it on GitHub

Comment: I'm using this commit of the webARonARCore browser because at that time the newest one was crashing: https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARCore/commit/22b75c18d4aeb4232e47556cc27f067f4115c75b

Comment: The workaround for using the older commit was suggested in this thread: https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARCore/issues/44

Comment: I checked the installation guides to WebAR and it seems to be pointing to the first release. So MAYBE it uses preview 1

Comment: Don't expect things to work properly if you're using any work around or if you're not using a stable release of arcore. If there are bugs/issues in the newest version of arcore, report them/add your experience to GitHub. Don't report issues for outdated code or code that google didn't write.

Comment: It looks like the webar code was updated within the last month, so make sure you're using the new code/browser. (it's not so clear to me how the web AR is working and how it relates to arcore...it might not technically be arcore.) I'd make sure to uninstall any old versions of the browser or whatever you have to install on your phone. Also if there's any google code you have to add to your project, make sure that uses all newest code from Google. Sorry for any misspellings or if things don't make sense, I'm still waking up :)

Comment: Hey Nerk, thanks for the heads up, if i want to make sure i tried the newest available technology i'll have to uninstall the preview 1 and 2 and the webAROnARCore browser and take the newest of everything and see if it works. I'll probably try this later today

Comment: Alright here's what i did: Uninstall everything off my phone. Then use adb to install this: https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARCore/tree/webarcore_57.0.2987.5/apk

Then when i start it up it says: no arcore detected, click here to open the link. Then it brings me to a lorem ipsum page.. wonderfull.. So i download ARCore preview2, start the browser and again it tells me 'arcore missing'

Comment: so i use adb to install the preview 1 i still had laying around and it starts up, shows the examples page for 1 or 2 seconds before crashing. Just like before.

Comment: https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARCore/issues/47
In case anyone was wondering, one of the devs is taking a look at it here

Comment: Great. That's weird that webar is still using the preview 1 apk. Seems like a form of fragmentation to me.